# How can I get correct shipping cost and tax on a list of amazon items?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, parsing

I am looking for a method of correctly getting info (especially shipping and tax) given an input of an amazon wishlist (test case: http://amzn.com/w/2EHKBBH44AWPL)

Ideally, I'd like to get the exact tax/shipping charges that would be seen in the checkout screen [image: checkout screen shot]

Info needed:

Item(s)

- Name
- ASIN
- Price
- Tax
- Shipping cost
- Is item fulfilled by Amazon (T/F)?

City/State of shipping address that wishlist is to be sent to.

Current method:

1. Parse the wishlist for ASIN/name/price/shipping address
2. User Amazon Affiliate API to obtain ASIN/name/price
3. Add items to cart and go to checkout to parse for tax/shipping

Challenges:

- Amazon changes their markup to prevent parsing
- Tax varies depending on city
- Amazon Marketplace merchants do not have consistent tax/shipping charges
- Other problems

I am using python but open to hearing any language or implementation method, regardless of elegance.

Answer (score 1):

You should go for this `Amazon-API`: https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't get shipping cost, if it's primer eligible, nor taxes.

You could calculate the taxes based on the person State and product type, but the API doesn't give these details. Sadly, using a bot to check prices by yourself isn't allowed.